# Angular. Mi formulario envía los datos aunque no cumplan con los validators

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, formularios

soy nuevo en angular y estoy intentando crear un formulario con Validators, los errores se muestran
[image: evidencia del error]
pero al momento de darle en enviar igual se envían los datos y se guardan en la BD.

este es mi código del group:

```
this.signUpForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
});
```

y este es mi código de formulario:

```
<form [formGroup]="signUpForm" (ngSubmit)="functioncall()">
<app-input name="name" title="Nombre"></app-input>
<app-input name="email" title="Email"></app-input>
<app-input-pass name="password" title="Contraseña" [control]="passwordField"></app-input-pass>
<!-- <app-input-pass name="confirmPassword" title="Verificar Contraseña" [password1]="passwordField.value"  [control]="confirmPasswordField">
</app-input-pass> -->
<div class="containerButtons">
  <app-button [type]="'submit'" type="submit" [type]="'submit'" [class]="'primary'" [label]="'Registrarse'">
  </app-button>
  <app-button [class]="'basic'" [label]="'Iniciar sesion'" [routerLink]="'login'"></app-button>
</div>
```

Me podrían ayudar con eso por favor, si necesitan más datos los responderé inmediatamente.

Comment: pudieras añadir a tu pregunta el codigo de `functioncall()` de tu archivo `componen.ts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que dentro de método `functioncall()` en tú `component.ts` deberías poner una condicional así

```
functioncall(){

if (this.signUpForm.invalid) {
      this.signUpForm.markAllAsTouched()
      return
    }

// aquí el código para guardar en la base de datos

}
```

Con esto garantizas que si por equivocación el usuario hace clic en el botón `Registrarse` no envié los datos con error, ni vacios a la base de datos